# Evolution of maximum of first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maxima-minima

This is my first question, I hope it's not a duplicate or too easy:

I have a first order PDE for a function $\omega(x,t)$ of position $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and time $t \in [0,\infty]$:
$$
\partial_t \omega = -\ln(1+e^{x}) - v \partial_x \omega + \frac{D}{2} (\partial_x \omega)^2
$$
Where $v,D>0$ are real positive constants. The initial condition are:
$$
\omega(x,t=0) = -(x - \mu)^2 
$$
With again $\mu>0$ real positive constant. I am interested in studying the evolution of the maximum of $\omega(x,t)$ over time. At initial time $\omega(x,t=0)$ has maximum at $x=\mu$. As time goes on how does the maximum evolve? Can I write a differential equation for its evolution? I believe that this maximum will converge to a fixed value at infinite time.

Thanks to you in advance!

Ps: ultimately my aim is finding the convergence value of the maximum at infinite time (hoping there is one). Any technique which allows to find this would do the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the auxiliary problem without the $-\ln(1+e^x)$ source term using separation of variables and the use Green's Functions to include the source term.

References:

M. N. Ozisik, Heat Conduction, 2nd Edition, J.Wiley & Sons, 1993. (See Chapter 6)

H.S. Carslaw & Jaeger, Conduction of Heat in Solids, Oxford Clarendon Press, 1959.

Comment: It is not a heat equation. It is a first order nonlinear equation because of the quadratic term $(\partial_x\omega)^2$.

Comment: WHOA! I read that as $\partial^2_x \omega$. Could the OP confirm that it is indeed a quadratic as Julian pointed out.

Comment: Never mind! The "First Order" should've been a good clue! :-)

In that case, the references (while fantastic in their own right) are not relevant. 

You could differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$ and obtain a non-homogeneous wave equation as

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \bigl(Dy-v\bigr) \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}-\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}
$$

where $y=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} $

but I'm not sure a closed form solution exists.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar sorry for the delay. And thank you again. Yes, it's first order, no second derivative. And yes, the problem would be then to study the evolution in time of the zeros of $y$.

Comment: Are you seeking a closed form solution or would you consider a finite difference approach?  If the latter, then the best methods are the Fourth Order Leapfrog and Lax-Wendroff. MIT's open courseware has some excellent tutorials on this.

Comment: A closed form solution would be the best thing. Or rather, even the limit for $t \rightarrow \infty$ of the zeros of this equation would be enough. But in the meantime I will give a look at MIT's open courses. They will give me at least some intuition!